# Live site with Fancy Box Issues Please

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm having issues with the fancybox plugins, can yo check my code please. When you scroll on a image in firefox it seems that the you need to  click on the screen and it then ape ares.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
}); 
</script>

<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
        // will loop through 
var images = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + $(this).attr("href");
var linkimage = 'user-uploads/' + $(this).attr("href");
// back up $('<p><a href="' + linkimage + '"><img class="resizeme" src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
$('<p><a class="fancybox" href="' + linkimage + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img class="resizeme" src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
     });
  }
});
//linkimage is user-uploads directory which contains the larger file for fancy box
//user-uploads-thumbnails is only so i can pull smaller images for the infite scroll
//<a href="user-uploads/"'linkimages'"/" >
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is not well referenced:

http://ilovesmallies.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

When i visit your website, i get that :

> GET
>   /fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3
>   404 (Not Found) showcase.php:57 
>   GET
>   /scripts/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5
>   404 (Not Found) showcase.php:57 
>   GET
>   /fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5
>   404 (Not Found) showcase.php:57 
>   GET
>   /fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7
>   404 (Not Found) showcase.php:57

I think you have a link problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to fix :

**ONE** : use a single instance of jQuery (ideally the latest version) So far you are loading two : v1.8.2 and v1.7.2

**TWO** : as previously pointed out, your fancybox CSS stylesheet isn't found (404). You have to reference it with the proper path:

Current : http://ilovesmallies.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3(404)

Real : http://ilovesmallies.com/forum/scripts/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3